# Conditional lookbehind

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I really do not fully understand the concept of the conditional feature of regex. At least I don't get it to work.
So I want to match the following strings

```
28.11 16.12
"13.01 23,09"
01.08.-31.12
"01.01,-51.12"
"01,01.-31,12."
01083112
1.02 - 4.3
```

using the following regex

```
 \D*(?P<from_day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■\-]*
(?P<from_month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■\-]*
(?P<until_day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■\-]*
(?P<until_month>1[012]|0?[1-9]).*|.+
```

Which works just fine but now I also want to accept
`2811 16.12` or `28.11 16.12`,
but not `2811 1612` or `28111612`,
so one separator in between the group of up to 4 digits should be present.

I tried with a simpler regex https://regex101.com/r/j5JL0u/1,
but I did not get it to work.

Comment: What language/platform/framework/application are you using?

Comment: For what I can understand, I think just using lookahead is fine (example: [`(?=.*\d{1,2}[,.]+\d{1,2}[,.]*).+`](https://regex101.com/r/oe8Kxz/1)), why do you think you need conditional regexps?

Comment: You realize `01083112` previously ok is the same as `28111612` that now is bad ..

Comment: Fwiw you cannot control free text quantities without boundary's. For example  _`so one separator in between the group of up to 4 digits should be present`_ cannot be solved with a simple validation of the negative failure like `(?!.*\d{5})` since there is no end just `.*` which is not a constraint. Unless you have constant boundary's, the only thing you can do is lay out all the permutations in a large alternation scheme.

Comment: Another approach is to capture the separators as well, then rewrite the dates with the included max 4 digits per separator. This will bring the dates into a formatted compliance. I'm sure this won't be a problem since this is just a bunch of mumbo jumbo random, non-machine generated text.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match those whole lines with the named capture groups, you can make use of a positive lookahead to assert a "separator" other than a whitespace char (note that `\s` can also match a newline) 2-4 digits.

The anchors `^` and `$` assert the start and the end of the string.

The string `"01.01,-51.12"` is not matched, as your current pattern also would not match `51`

The string `01083112` does not match, a there is no separator as all present.

```
^"?(?=.*\b\d\d?[.\s,■\-]\d\d?\b)(?P<from_day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■\-]*(?P<from_month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■\-]*(?P<until_day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■\-]*(?P<until_month>1[012]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■\-]*"?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `"?` Match an optional `"`
- `(?=.*\b\d\d?[.\s,■\-]\d\d?\b)` Positive lookahead, assert one of `[.\s,■\-]` between 2-4 digits. The word boundary `\b` prevents a partial word match.
- `(?P<from_day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■\-]*(?P<from_month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])` The *from_day* and *from_month* patterns
- `[.\s,■\-]*` Optionally repeat matching one of `[.\s,■\-]`
- `(?P<until_day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■\-]*(?P<until_month>1[012]|0?[1-9])` The *until_day* and *until_month* patterns`
- `[.\s,■\-]*` Match optional allowed trailing characters
- `"?`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nUKjUo/1).

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this will not fully satisfy the requirement; I'm merely providing the answer as a starting point to, or reference for, possibly providing some sort of insight to a solution.

> *"... one separator in between the group of up to 4 digits should be present."*

This will contradict your provided value of, *01083112*.

Considering the complexity of the pattern, I recommend evaluating the captured values within the program, as opposed to within the pattern.

The following will capture the values, with the exception for, *01083112*.

```
^[^\d]*(\d\d?)[^\d]+(\d\d?)[^\d]+(\d\d?)[^\d]+(\d\d?)[^\d]*$
```

And, with your named groups.

```
^[^\d]*(?P<from_day>\d\d?)[^\d]+(?P<from_month>\d\d?)[^\d]+(?P<until_day>\d\d?)[^\d]+(?P<until_month>\d\d?)[^\d]*$
```

If you *did* want to check all of the conditions within the pattern, the *conditional statement* is not necessarily required.

The current method you're using, where you're checking the day against a specific month value, is correct.
This is the typical way to achieve this, in regex.

As a note, since they are date values, there will be leap years.
So, you'll have to also check for *29* days for February.

For reference, *IPv4 address* validity is sometimes achieved with a similar concept.
This is from the following book, *[O'Reilly Media – Regular Expressions Cookbook – 7.16. Matching IPv4 Addresses](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html)*.

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

Comment: Why would you want to match an ip address here? The other 2 patterns also match `2811 1612` and `28111612`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, for reference ...